Can ColorConfiguration be used with Gradients in Watch Face Format?
In <UserConfigurations>, I have:
        <ColorConfiguration id="colour" defaultValue="0" displayName="color_selector_display_name">
            <ColorOption id="0" displayName="colours_tertiary" colors="#ff0000ff #ff00ff00 #ffff0000 #ff000000"/>
            <ColorOption id="1" displayName="colours_saturation" colors="#ff004000 #ff00a000 #ff00ff00 #ff000000"/>
        </ColorConfiguration>

In a <SweepGradient>, I have:
colors="[CONFIGURATION.colour.0] [CONFIGURATION.colour.1] [CONFIGURATION.colour.2] [CONFIGURATION.colour.3]"

But the element is drawn white, as though every entry in colors were #ffffffff. I can't see any runtime errors reported.
When I 'hard-code' colour values into colors, I see them, so I think that the <SweepGradient> is correct.
When I apply [CONFIGURATION.colour.1] to an element that doesn't use a gradient, I see it, so I think that the <ColorConfiguration> is correct.
Is it possible to apply colours from a <ColorConfiguration> to a gradient?
